How to use the pytorch-grad-cam library to make visualization for a specific tag for the Faster rcnn reset 50 fpn v2 model
I use EigenCAM from the library unfortunately, there is no example in the guide and documentation of how to make a visualization for a specific class. I tried to write my own function for the class based on FasterRCNNBoxScoreTargetb so that I could cut off tags that I don't need, but the result hasn't changed. I think it can be done much easier, I just don't understand how
